# Understanding proof about chromatic number

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, combinatorial-topology

Consider an undirected graph $K(n,k,i)$, with the all $k$-element subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ as vertices, and two vertices connected by an edge if their sets intersect in less than $i$ elements.

This [paper](https://cdm.ucalgary.ca/cdm/index.php/cdm/article/download/557/259) claims on page 74 (Theorem 5.1) that the chromatic number of $K(n,k,i)$ is at least $n-2k+2i$. However, their is a place in the proof of the theorem which I don't understand: They say that

> Otherwise we would have two $k$-subsets of
>   color $j$ such that each of them has at least $k - i + 1$ elements in one of two
>   disjoint hemispheres, so their intersection has at most $i-1$ elements which is
>   impossible.

Since the intersection can be of size up to $i-1$ in each hemisphere, don't we only get that it has size at most $2i-2$ in total?

Comment: i-1 points are not on a hemisphere, there are on a hypersphere, a sphere of codimension 1.

Comment: @ArseniyAkopyan Why can't they be in the other hemisphere?

Comment: @BenBarber At most $i-1$ points of the first $k$-set are in the second $k$-set's hemisphere, and vice versa. Doesn't that make for $2i-2$ points available for intersection?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  The argument is of a different shape from that of Greene which it claims to generalise.  I'll have a ponder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a genuine logical error.  If $k$ is at least twice $i-1$ and $n$ is large enough that we can cover the sphere in a fine dust, then almost any pair of antipodal points will correspond to hemispheres $H_1$, $H_2$ containing at least $k-i+1$ points from sets $S_1$, $S_2$  with intersection of size $2(i-1)$.

Comment: I imagine you get a similar result by adding a factor of $2$ somewhere appropriate in the statement, but it looks like you'd need a new idea to get the result claimed.